# How to add the data in HTML page from Flask

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

```
@blueprint.route("/register/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def register():
    """Register new user."""
    form = RegisterForm(request.form)
    print(form, form.username.data)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        User.create(
            username=form.username.data,
            email=form.email.data,
            password=form.password.data,
            active=True,
        )
        flash("Thank you for registering. You can now log in.", "success")
        return redirect(url_for("public.home"))
    else:
        flash_errors(form)
    return render_template("public/register.html", form=form)
```

This is my registration code, I am facing a challenge where I have to add username to the UI page and this remains in page in all the different segments (on the website which I am building).

Since username is required everywhere, I have added the part where I need it, to the `base.html` and importing/ loading this in all my other pages.

Currently, I'm not able to set up the part where the username from the database is taken and added to the HTML page.

In this part on the HTML page, I want to import this

```
              <div class="user-card user-card--skin-dark notification-item-padding-x" style="background-image: '{{  asset_url_for("media/misc/bg-1.jpg")}}'">
                <div class="user-card__avatar">
                  <img alt="Pic" class="hidden" src="{{ asset_url_for('media/users/300_25.jpg') }}">
                   <span class="badge badge--lg badge--rounded badge--bold font-success">
        {{user.username}}
                  </span>
                </div>
                <div class="user-card__name">
                  {{user.first_name}
                </div>

              </div>
```

But I am not able to add this. Can anyone help me with this?

ps I am not good with the front end technologies and have said almost 0 knowledge of javascript

Comment: May that be happened because you did not send the context to the render_template ?
Is the user class sending its values automatically to the html page ? 
I would try to check in the html page what {{ form }} outputs since this is the only context you sent to the template.

Comment: @JimErginbash i am testing this , from the html i am able to send the data to backend, but from backend to html i am testing it. issue is my project is made with cookiecutter flask and all the thing is messed up in current code base, so fixing 1 thing at a time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check 'User Loader Function' function. A snap of code is given below :

In models.py

```
from app import login
@login.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    return User.query.get(int(id))
```

In routes.py

```
from flask_login import current_user, login_user
from app.models import User
@blueprint.route("/register/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def register():
    """Register new user."""
    form = RegisterForm(request.form)
    print(form, form.username.data)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        User.create(
            username=form.username.data,
            email=form.email.data,
            password=form.password.data,
            active=True,
        )
        flash("Thank you for registering. You can now log in.", "success")
        return redirect(url_for("public.home"))
    else:
        flash_errors(form)
    return render_template("public/register.html", form=form)
```

In html

```
      <div class="user-card user-card--skin-dark notification-item-padding-x" style="background-image: '{{  asset_url_for("media/misc/bg-1.jpg")}}'">
        <div class="user-card__avatar">
          <img alt="Pic" class="hidden" src="{{ asset_url_for('media/users/300_25.jpg') }}">
           <span class="badge badge--lg badge--rounded badge--bold font-success">
{{current_user.username}}
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="user-card__name">
          {{user.first_name}
        </div>

      </div>
```

For better explanation check the [link](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-v-user-logins).

Comment: thanks, it self, i had to modify the core base library. this help me understand a little better